# In angular build files, how to have the same folder structure as component?

Tags: angular, typescript

Whenever we hit `ng build`, all the components are compiled into index.html and main.js file. But I need to have the same folder structure of component in the build file as well.

```
My component 
src
->app
    -> app.component.html
    -> app.component.ts
    -> app.component.css
    -> register
        -> register.html
        -> register.ts
        -> register.css

Expected output
dist
    ->app
        -> index.html
        -> index.css
        -> main.js
        ->register
            -> index.html
            -> style.css
            -> main.js
```

This might look like an overburden, but for my use case, I want each component to be build separate. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify why. You’re asking for a very strange thing from a framework primarily focused on single page applications.

Comment: I have to integrate angular application with SAP IAS tenant for authentication. I want to remove authentication for 3 pages alone. To do that I need to have separate html file. That's how we can achieve it in SAP IAS.